# ZK Selenium testing. How to use it?

Tags: selenium, zk

I'm beginner in AQC. I want to know how to use ZK Selector with Selenium IDE. But I can't find any information about integrating ZK in Selenium.

So, how can I make my Selenium IDE to record scripts using  ZK. And how to use this scripts like  ZTL tests?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance and greetings from Ukraine.

Comment: If you are using any third party IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ, you can integrate Slenium Webdriver jar files and ZK.

Answer (score 1):

very useful articles:

http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2013/July/ZK_Testing_with_Selenium_IDE
http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2009/February/How_to_Test_ZK_Application_with_Selenium
http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Testing/Testing_Tips

Greetings from Ukraine

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to test your ZK applications is **ZTL**. Did you used this product? This is a official tool for testing for more information you can browse below link .

[ZTL](http://www.zkoss.org/product/ztl)

[ZK Selenium testing without UUIDs](http://blog.zkoss.org/index.php/2010/05/25/zk-selenium-testing-without-uuids/)

May be this will you .